# How to Split or Slice the text inside a coulmn in CSV file using python script or Shell?

Tags: python, linux, shell

1. Row1_1368083_US_PBPR_STD
2. Row215_1368083_US_PBPR_ENH
3. Row216_60902413_US_PBPR_ENH
4. Row227_37758281_US_PBPR_ENH

The final output should only be **1368083** numbers in a column

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions that have been asked and answered so many times you have to make an effort to avoid finding an answer. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.split`

```
s1 = "Row1_1368083_US_PBPR_STD"
s2 ="Row215_1368083_US_PBPR_ENH"

print(s1.split("_")[1])
print(s2.split("_")[1])
```

**Output:**

```
1368083
1368083
```

Or Regex.

```
import re

s1 = "Row216_60902413_US_PBPR_ENH"
s2 ="Row227_37758281_US_PBPR_ENH"

print(re.findall(r"\d{6,}", s1)[0])
print(re.findall(r"\d{6,}", s2)[0])
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `sed` to extract the digit part between two '_',

```
sed 's/^.*_\([0-9]*\)_.*/\1/'
```

Or use `awk` to extract the 2nd field separated by '_',

```
awk -F'_' '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
awk -F_ '$2 ~/1368083/{print $2}' file
1368083
1368083
```

Comment: You should explain how this solves the question.  It works for examples 1 and 2, not for 3 and 4.

Comment: AFAIK we are not supposed to print 3 and 4.

Comment: Indeed, not super clear from the question, I assumed differently than you did.  FYI, I did not down-vote your answer.