# How to compare two columns in same file and store the difference in new file with the unchanged column according to it?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

```
Row    Actual    Expected 
 1      AAA        BBB
 2      CCC        CCC
 3      DDD        EEE
 4      FFF        GGG
 5      HHH        HHH
```

I want to compare actual and expected and store the difference in a file. Like

```
Row    Actual   Expected
 1      AAA       BBB
 3      DDD       EEE
 4      FFF       GGG
```

I have used `awk -F, '{if ($2!=$3) {print $1,$2,$3}}' Sample.csv` It will only compare Int values not String value

Comment: Look at [cut](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html), [diff](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/diff.1.html) and [paste](https://linux.die.net/man/1/paste).. And [please avoid "Give me the codez" questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51588641).

Answer (score 1):

You can use AWK to do this

```
awk '{if($2!=$3) print $0}' oldfile > newfile
```

where

- $2 and $3 are second and third columns
- != means second and third columns does not match
- $0 means whole line
- > newfile redirects to new file

Comment: You may direct use `awk '$2!=$3' oldfile > newfile`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the file uses tab or some other delimiter to separate the columns, then [tsv-filter](https://ebay.github.io/tsv-utils/docs/tool_reference/tsv-filter.html) from [eBay's TSV Utilities](https://github.com/eBay/tsv-utils) supports this type of field comparison directly. For the file above:

```
$ tsv-filter --header --ff-str-ne 2:3 file.tsv
Row Actual  Expected
1   AAA BBB
3   DDD EEE
4   FFF GGG
```

The `--ff-str-ne` option compares two fields in a row for non-equal strings.

Disclaimer: I'm the author.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer an `awk` solution (can handle more fields and easier to understand), but you could use

```
sed -r '/\t([^ ]*)\t\1$/d' Sample.csv
```